# How to write to the alternate screen buffer on Windows using only the standard libary?

Tags: winapi, rust, output, buffer, handle

I am working on an alternate screen feature for my cross-platform terminal manipulating crate.

**Situation**

When I want to write something to console I can use the following code to write to the current [standard output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdout.html). This works on both UNIX and Windows systems:

```
write!(::std::fmt::io::stdout(), "Some text").
```

When I switch to the alternate screen, I don't want to write to the current [standard output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdout.html) but to the alternate screen. This works differently depending on which platform you are on. The basics are the same: I need to store the handle somewhere globally so that I could put the stored `output handle` in alternate screen mode and write all my output, commands and actions to that stored `output handle`.

When I am in alternate mode, my code writes to the alternate screen and when in main screen modes my code writes to the main screen.

- *Unix*

  For UNIX systems, I can use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to switch to the [alternate screen and back](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288962/what-does-1049h-and-1h-ansi-escape-sequences-do). I store the `::std::io::stdout()` somewhere and all my UNIX code uses that handle for access to the terminal `output`. When in alternate screen mode, all the `write`s I do are done on the alternate screen and when on the main screen all the `write`s are done on the main screen.
- *Windows*

  For Windows systems, I can use [WinAPI](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) to [switch to the alternate screen buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-and-writing-blocks-of-characters-and-attributes). I'll create a new screen buffer with [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) then I'll use [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer) to change the active buffer. At last, I need to store the handle gotten from `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`. Through this output handle, I can write output to the alternate screen buffer.

If I would not have used the above-described way and switched to alternate screen and just called this `write!(::std::fmt::io::stdout(), "Some text")`, I would write to the main screen instead of the alternate screen on both Windows and Unix systems because `stdout()` is a handle to the [standard output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdout.html).

**The Question**

The way described above works to a certain point; when I want to write to the stored handle.

For Unix I can do the following:

```
// (...) some logic to get the handle to the current screen.
let stored_handle: Write = ...;
write!(stored_handle, "Some text);
```

But for Windows I could **not** do this:

```
// (...) some logic to get the handle to the current screen for windows.
let stored_handle: HANDLE = ...;
write!(stored_handle, "Some text);
```

I could implement `std::io::Write` for the struct where I store the `stdout` so that for Windows I create my own logic for writing to the console with WinAPI. If I would do that I would be able to write to that struct like the following:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
let storage = WindowsScreenManager::new();
#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
let storage = UnixScreenManager::new();

write!(storage, "Some text");
```

This is not ideal for my situation because I can not use the Rust string escape characters like `\n \t` my string will not contain any newlines or tabs when doing it this way. Think because WinAPI does not know these formatting options.  Also I don't want to manage all the writing to the console for Windows manually on my side.

I really want to use the WinAPI `HANDLE` as `std::io::Write` so that it can be used in the `write!` macro, just like I do in UNIX. Just store the `stdout()` and write to that `stdout()` using the `write!` macro, but storing the `HANDLE` and writing to that.

I suppose that this should work since when calling `println!()` or `write!(stdout())` on Windows it will write the to the standard output handle of the current process. But now I want to write to the alternate handle and not only to the default handle. Or am I wrong with this?

If the above cannot be done, how would I write to the alternate screen `HANDLE` without using my own implementation for writing to the Console using WinAPI?

Comment: Escapes like `\n` and `\t` in strings are replaced at compile time. What, exactly, is the problem you're having with them?

Comment: If I use them I get some weird symbols in my console. Maybe because I encoded it to utf16 (which needs to be done) before writing it to the console using  `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA`. Plus that it adds some complexity on my side of handling all the writing to the console using WinAPI.

Comment: IIRC `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA` is for ANSI strings. If you encoded the string in UTF-16 (UniCode) the correct function would be [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter).

Comment: Still the same result the [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b934c26597860b7d421f302360612a7e&version=stable&mode=debug) The backslashes are still shown as the symbols.

Comment: Does it do the same if you replace the body of `win32_string` with `value.encode_utf16().collect()`? I don't think `encode_wide` actually transcodes from UTF-8 to UTF-16; `OsStr` can be arbitrary bytes.

Comment: @trentcl If I do it like you are saying I get text like S o m e t e x t in the console. And also the escape sequence characters are shown like weird symbols.